# Using for loop to append vectors of variable length

Tags: r, loops, variables, vector, append

I am trying to create a vector or list of values based on the output of a function performed on individual elements of a column.

```r
library(hpoPlot)
xyz_hpo <- c("HP:0003698", "HP:0007082", "HP:0006956")

getallancs <- function(hpo_col) {
  for (i in 1:length(hpo_col)) {
    anc <- get.ancestors(hpo.terms, hpo_col[i])
    output <- list()
    output[[length(anc) + 1]] <- append(output, anc)
  }
  return(anc)
}

all_ancs <- getallancs(xyz_hpo)
```

get.ancestors outputs a character vector of variable length depending on each term. How can I loop through hpo_col adding the length of each ancs vector to the output vector?

Comment: Put `output <- list()` outside your `for`-loop (before it) and `return(output)` instead of `return(anc)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Great job on providing a minimal reproducible example!

As mentioned in the comments, you need to move the `output <- list()` outside of your `for` loop, and return it after the loop. At present it is being reset for each iteration of the loop, which is not what you want. I also think you want to return a vector rather than a list, so I have changed the type of `output`.

Also, in your original question, you say that you want to return the length of each `anc` vector in the loop, so I have changed the function to output the length of each iteration, rather than the whole vector.

```r
getallancs <- function(hpo_col) {
    output <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:length(hpo_col)) {
        anc <- get.ancestors(hpo.terms, hpo_col[i])
        output <- append(output, length(anc))
    }
    return(output)
}
```

If you are only doing this for a few cases, such as your example, this approach will be fine, however, this paradigm is typically quite slow in R and it's better to try and [vectorise](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html) this style of calculation if possible. This is especially important if you are running this for a large number of elements where computation will take more than a few seconds.

For example, one way the function above could be vectorised is like so:

```r
all_ancs <- sapply(xyz_hpo, function(x) length(get.ancestors(hpo.terms, x)))
```

If in fact you did mean to output the whole vector of `anc`, not just the lengths, the original function would look like this:

```r
getallancs <- function(hpo_col) {
    output <- character()
    for (i in 1:length(hpo_col)) {
        anc <- get.ancestors(hpo.terms, hpo_col[i])
        output <- c(output, anc)
    }
    return(output)
}
```

Or a vectorised version could be

```r
all_ancs <- unlist(lapply(xyz_hpo, function(x) get.ancestors(hpo.terms, x)))
```

Hope that helps. If it solves your problem, please mark this as the answer.